# Resources for Data models in blockchain

Tags: networking, blockchain, data-modeling, distributed-transactions, decentralized-applications

As I recently started my learning path towards blockchain I got essentials with basics of blockchain but when I come across these one's I have seen that there are many data model's or networking models revolving around like account based , transaction based and so on but when I tried to track these of models the resources available in the internet is of less clarity so I want a reliable and clear resource to study about the model's in the blockchain . so suggest or share some of the resources you know with that can be reliable through that I will get benefited